# How to connect Cloud9 (python) to Redshift in VPC?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, aws-api-gateway, vpc, aws-cloud9

I am aiming to build an API using API Gateway -> Lambda -> Redshift.  I'm working in Cloud9 to build the Lambda function.  My problem is that our Redshift is securely tucked away in a VPC.  I can whitelist an IP (for  developing locally), but since Cloud9/Lambda are serverless, they don't have a stable IP.

How do I put both the Cloud9 environment *and* the Lambda in the right spot so they can ping my database?

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](https://medium.com/financial-engines-techblog/aws-lambdas-with-a-static-outgoing-ip-5174a1e70245) has a step-by-step.  Setting up a VPC with a public and private subnets allow for a stable IP address.